# Something wrong with code suggestion (VS 2015)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

After updating Visual Studio 2015 I'm unable to do a ctrl + '.' for code suggestions.

Anyone have a suggestion for fixing this bug?

Comment: Can you be more specific on the error

Comment: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, version= 1.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: What is the version of VS

Comment: It could mean that the installation is somewhat corrupted. Perhaps try a repair?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 Version 2